# disordered/ordered context fetching

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, nsarray, nsfetchrequest

I cannot understanding why values assign to array objects become "disordered" after executing executeFetchRequest. Well, I'm not certain that fetching is the problem here. Here's the code.

```
objects=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",@"d",@"e",nil];

NSManagedObject *DB = nil;

for (int i=0;i<[objects count];i++){

DB = [NSEntityDescription                   
                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"dbTable" 
                inManagedObjectContext:context];

[DB setValue:[objects objectAtIndex:i] forKey:@"item"];
[DB setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%3.2f", 0] forKey:@"value"];       
}

objects = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

Printings

new wrong ordering after fetch execution into array objects
index 0 :: Item: d
index 1 :: Item: c
index 2 :: Item: e
index 3 :: Item: b
index 4 :: Item: a

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the underlying database architecture, Core Data stores all objects and to-many references in an unordered fashion.  The order you get back from a fetch request is not guaranteed, unless you apply an NSSortDescriptor, as Alex describes.  [This thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/message/cocoa/2005/6/11/138531) in the Cocoa mailing list details the issues involved, as well as some potential solutions.

These solutions include having an index property that you sort on when performing a fetch request, or implementing a linked list of managed objects and traversing that in order.  Brian Webster has created a subclass of NSManagedObject that lets you maintain ordered to-many relationships in your Core Data objects, for which the source code can be found [here](http://www.fatcatsoftware.com/blog/2008/per-object-ordered-relationships-using-core-data).

Comment: Hi Brad, yours and Alex's comments are very enlightening. Brian Webster subclassing is for to-many relationships, not my case. I think the idea for me is another attribute recording user entering order.. yeah, not a sophisticated one but proves working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Apply an `NSSortDescriptor` to your fetch request, e.g.:

```
NSSortDescriptor *itemDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"item" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:itemDescriptor, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
[sortDescriptors release];
[itemDescriptor release];
```

will sort on the `item` name. You could use `value`, instead.

Comment: Hi Alex,
I came across that idea too (although not knowing how to do it in obj-c). Now I know how. But what I'm after is to leave the items in the exact order they are entered by a user, and that without using one more attribute in my DB receiving entering order. Is that possible? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Unless the user enters the items in an order that can be used as a natural sort (i.e. the value being entered can be sorted on, as-is) I'm fairly sure you would need to use another key that stores the entry ordering, and then sort on that for the fetch.

Comment: I get the sense that, behind the scenes, managed object subclasses are thrown into bags of type `NSSet`. Members of a set have no particular order, because the only requirement for constructing a set is that members are unique. The fetch is what applies an ordering on what is read out of the set, assuming a sort descriptor is added to the fetch.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute a fetch request without specifying that you want your items sorted by a specific key, you get a result array which is not ordered. You can extend your fetch request with a sort descriptor using a code snippet such as the following one.

```
    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"value" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
```

Comment: Hi,
I think I misled you guys by putting alphabet ordered values, it was just to demonstrate after fetching results. What my problem really is, is that I want to keep user entering order, without additional attributes in DB. Thank you unforgiven.